# Keep some cell height unchanged, while changing others

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, heightforrowatindexpath

I have a TableView of static cells (with different heights) and I am trying to hide a cell on load. I achieved it by using `heightForRowAtIndexPath` and returning `0` for the cell I want to close, but, for that function, I need to return a value..

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
   if indexPath.section == 2 && indexPath.row == 5 {
       return 0
   }

   // here:

   return tableView.rowHeight  // changes default values of cells
   return UITableViewAutomaticDimension // changes too.

    }
```

I want to return whatever height cell has.

I found this for obj-c and I feel like it would work, but I am not sure.. I couldn't translate it..

```
[super tableView:tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
```

What is the way of keeping the cells' height as they have? Should I hardcode everything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just call the `super` implementation:

```
return super.tableView(tableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath: indexPath)
```